# Why am I not seeing the mission "Welcome Back, Commander" in World of Tanks?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I've logged in to one of my friend's account and he has these missions:

[image]

Today I've logged into my own account and I can't see these missions. What is the reason for that? I would really like to get a Dickermax for completing "Well Done, Commander!" on my own account. How is this possible?

Please note that my friend did not play WoT for quite a while now. Is it possible that this mission only appears after several months of inactivity? I tired to google it but it seems that no one has heard of it.

**edit:** I have checked the obvious places (mission menu, completed missions, etc) so please refrain from comments stating obvious things.

Comment: top left, there should be a missions button

Comment: I've cleaned up the comments here. Please refrain from insults and personal attacks.

Comment: that's only for players that did not played for 2 month straight... I'm guessing, that in your personal account, you've been playing :)

Comment: Is it exactly 2 months? That's what I thought too, thanks!